# Description of the audio streams in a video file

Tags: video, video-editing

Could someone point me in the right direction on creating these descriptions in the audio stream languages of a video file? Is that something that I need to do during the video's encoding? If so, what application should I use for that? Thank you.
[image] [image]

I tried to get these in Avidemux but can't find an option. Also, I tried to google, but the issue is that I don't know how to name these descriptions correctly.